# Apply conditional formatting to the whole data frame

Tags: r, formatting

How can I apply conditional formatting to the whole data frame?

```
formattable(data1, list(variable1=formatter("span", style=x ~ 
ifelse(x>2.24, style(color= "red", font.weight="bold"), NA))))
```

data1 is my data frame. Now, I am able to apply conditional formatting to one variable by specifying the variable name in the argument. However, I have 45 variables in total. Is there any way I can apply my condition (x > 2.24) to the whole data frame instead of applying that condition one column at a time?

Comment: You can use the `apply` statement with `MARGIN=2`, if you want to apply the same function across all columns.

Comment: Or use `lapply`.